# Get all products from subcategory in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

So I'm customizing a bigcommerce website and we've got a design that calls for a category page being broken up into it's subcategories. So for instance:

```
                        Parent Category
                          Sub Category
```

product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product

```
                           Sub Category
```

product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product    product

Unfortunately the bigcommerce subcategory object is currently very limited. In the docs it says:

- subcategories - List of any child categories id - Unique ID for the
  subcategory

  1. name - Name of the subcategory
  2. url- URL to the subcategory
  3. description - Merchant-defined description of the
     subcategory
  4. image - Image representing this subcategory, in Stencil
     image format
  5. product_count - Number of products in the subcategory.
     (Counts at the current level only – not recursive to deeper levels.)

So My question is if somebody has found a clever way around this to get the subcategory products.

Comment: Have you changed your category display settings to include subcategory products? http://i.imgur.com/cQLvMnp.png

Comment: That does help me display all the subcategory products, but it doesn't help me group them into subcategories.

Comment: That wasn't specified in your question. Can you illustrate what you've tried? I don't believe product cards include context for subcategories so it would have to be injected.

Comment: I've tried using some handlebar helpers to iterate through the the sub-categories ``{{#each categories.subcategories}}``, but this will only help me get the name of each subcategory. Not the subcategory's products themselves.

Comment: I'm exploring a similar issue with the concept of using the `{{inject}} + {{jsContext}}`  helpers and making a client side js app to store contexts to grab. Trying to make it so that if a subcategory has only one product the link would be directly to that product.

Comment: This would be an awesome bigcommerce plugin to allow for this!